# Replacing object in vector of derived objects "no matching function to call"

Tags: c++, object, vector, replace, shared-ptr

I have class `Employee` and derived class `Worker` and `Intern`. I store them in `vector<shared_ptr<Employee>> Firm;` Now I want to promote `Intern` to `Worker` by replacing derived object `Intern` in `vector` with `Worker`, with all the fields from `Employee` saved.

I've got:

```
void Promote(vector<shared_ptr<Employee>>& sourceEmployee) {

auto it = std::find_if(sourceEmployee.begin(), sourceEmployee.end(),
                              [&sourceEmployee, id](const auto &obj) { return obj->getID() == id; });

            if (it != sourceEmployee.end()) {
                auto index = std::distance(sourceEmployee.begin(), it);

                switch(sourceEmployee[index]->getnum()) { // returning num / recognizing specified class obj

                    case 0: {     // It's Intern, lets make him Worker
                        auto tmp0 = std::move(*it);
                        *it = std::make_shared<Worker>(*tmp0); // WORKING now
                        cout << "Employee " << id << " has been promoted" << endl;
                        break;
                    }

class Employee {
//basic c-tors etc.
protected:
    int employeeID;
    std::string Name;
    std::string Surname;
    int Salary;
    bool Hired;
};

class Intern : public Employee {

protected:
static const int num = 0;
};

class Worker : public Employee {

protected:
static const int num = 1;
};
```

So basically I need to destroy `Intern` object and create `Worker` instead in same place.

EDIT: Solved. I needed to make proper constructor and add `*` before `tmp)` ^_^

Comment: Suppose you have managed to replace your object. So what's the point of having a `shared_ptr<Employee>` then? Everybody who had a link to the old object will continue to hold it.

Comment: I thought I would prevent that by calling `.reset()`, wouldn't I?

Comment: No it wouldn't. `reset` affects one shared pointer.

Comment: `Worker::Worker(const Employee &)` **is not** a copy constructor, it is a normal constructor that takes a `Employee` as a parameter. A copy constructor would be `Worker::Worker(const Worker &)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you `Worker` does not have a constructor taking `std::shared_ptr<Employee>`, as the compiler tells you.

In this line:

```
*it = std::make_shared<Worker>(tmp0);
```

`std::make_shared` will construct the object by calling a constructor with `tmp0` as argument.

Side note: you don't have to do this: `(*it).reset()`. By calling `std::move` line above, you already reset the shared pointer.

Comment: So I need to create a move constructor for `Worker`?

Comment: Up to you :) You need to add a constructor and call it with appropriate arguments. In you example, you're trying to pass `std::shared_ptr<Employee>` to to ctor, so it wouldn't be a move constructor (move ctor would take rvalue reference to `Worker`).

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what to do now ^^

Comment: I figured it out :) needed copy constructor and `(*tmp0)`